# Role based authentication in HapiJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I am working on a rest API first project written with HapiJS. 
After the login process the user gets a token to pass in the header of every request.
Users have different roles (admin, standard, guest, partners) and some Api endpoint are reachable only by users with a certain role.
Someone could help me in defining this check in a nice way, so without writing the check everytime inside the route?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Scopes**

You can use `scopes` in hapi. When you authenticate the request by checking the header, you can set the `scope` property of the user's credentials:

```
var validateFunc = function (username, password, callback) {

    ... // Your logic here

    return callback(null, true, {scope: 'admin'});
};
```

When defining a route you can set the `scopes` which are permitted to that endpoint in the `config.auth.scope` property:

```
server.route({
    ...
    config: {
        auth: {
            strategy: 'simple', 
            scope: ['user', 'admin']
        },
    }
    ...
});
```

Now, only users who are authenticated with the scope of `user` or `admin`, will be able to access that route.

**Process**

1. Decide on some scopes (admin, superuser, guest etc)
2. Configure your authentication routine to correctly set the `scope` on the user's credentials
3. Configure your routes by setting the `config.auth.scope` to whomever is allowed to access it

**Runnable Example**

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 4000 });

server.register(require('hapi-auth-basic'), function (err) {

    if(err) {
        throw err;
    }

    server.auth.strategy('simple', 'basic', {
        validateFunc: function (username, password, callback) {

            if (username === 'admin') {
                return callback(null, true, {scope: 'admin'}); // They're an `admin`
            }
            if (username === 'user') {
                return callback(null, true, {scope: 'user'}); // They're a `user`
            }
            return callback(null, false);
        }
    });

    server.route([{
            config: {
                auth: {
                    strategy: 'simple', 
                    scope: ['admin']                    // Only admin
                },
            },
            method: 'GET',
            path: '/admin',
            handler: function(request, reply) {

                reply('Admin page');
            }
        }, {
            config: {
                auth: {
                    strategy: 'simple', 
                    scope: ['user', 'admin']            // user or admin
                },
            },
            method: 'GET',
            path: '/user',
            handler: function(request, reply) {

                reply('User page');
            }
        }
    ]);

    server.start(function () {
        console.log('Started server');
    });
});
```

Comment: where you get the return of callback of validateFunc i mean in handler or where? I want the result of validateFunc in case of implicit API created by Rest-Hapi module.Or in detail please check:-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546596/how-to-get-result-of-validatefunc-in-pre-of-auto-created-api-rest-hapi