# How to get result of validateFunc in pre of auto created API Rest Hapi

Tags: node.js, rest, jwt, hapi.js

I am new to Hapi.js.I am using **"hapi-auth-jwt2"** module for authentication token and role verification. I set the scope and sent that scope from the callback of validateFunc . It will worked very well for checking te role based authentication. But i want the result  i am returning from the **validateFunc** but don't know where i can get that.

```
validateFunc: function (token, request, callback) {
            Async.auto({
                session: function (done) {
                    Session.findByCredentials(token.sessionId, token.sessionKey, done);
                },
                user: ['session', function (results, done) {

                    if (!results.session) {
                        return done();
                    }

                    User.findById(results.session.user, done);
                }],
            }, (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    return callback(err);
                }

                if (!results.session) {
                    return callback(null, false);
                }
                results.scope = token.scope;
                callback(null, Boolean(results.user), results);
            });
        }
    });


};
`
```

It verify the scope or Role in the domain i.e:-

```
  routeOptions: {
                scope:{
                    createScope:"admin"
                }, 
  create: {
        pre : function(payload, Log){
            console.log("preee runnnig........");
            console.log(payload);
        }
      }
```

I am getting the payload Json what i am sending from the client side but i want the results i am sending from the callback of validateFunc, because i want to use that data here in pre prior to send the request.**I am working on implicitly created API via Rest Hapi Module.**

So how can i get that datain pre hooks from the validateFunc . Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a feature that is being worked on and hopefully will be done soon.

For now, you can [omit the generated create endpoint](https://github.com/JKHeadley/rest-hapi/blob/master/README.md#omitting-routes) and [replace it with your own](https://github.com/JKHeadley/rest-hapi/blob/master/README.md#standalone-endpoints) in order to access the request object.

The resulting code would look something like this:

```
'use strict';

const RestHapi = require('rest-hapi');

module.exports = function (server, mongoose, logger) {
    server.route({
      method: 'POST',
      path: '/pathName',
      config: {
        handler: function(request, reply) { 
          /* modify request.payload here and access auth info through request.auth.credentials */

          const Model = mongoose.model('modelName');
          return RestHapi.create(Model, request.payload, logger)
            .then(function (result) {
              return reply(result);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              return reply(error);
            });
        },
        tags: ['api'],
        plugins: {
          'hapi-swagger': {}
        }
      }
    });
};
```